# Notification not getting shown in one of IOS device

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

I am facing problem with notification. Notification is not getting shown in device from last 12 hours. It was working earlier. Sending to other devices works fine. 
I checked notification center and other thing. Notification is enabled for app.

After following 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html
I have enabled Enabling Push Status Messages on iOS.

On console , device is printing some information like:

```
<Error>: kDataAttachStatusNotification sent, wasAttached: 1 isAttached: 1
```

What does it mean ? Is it getting notification from server side and failing to show and receive due to some reason ?

Edit:
After syncing logs with itunes. Logs says something like:

```
2013-08-01 10:51:06 +0530 apsd[76]: _getClientIdentity: already had identity: <SecIdentityRef: (some value here)>
wasUp NO isUp NO linkQualityBelowAndWOWAvail: YES wantsInterfaceAssertion YES  avoidWWANOnCall NO
2013-08-01 10:51:06 +0530 apsd[76]: _getClientIdentity: already had identity: <SecIdentityRef: (some value here)>
2013-08-01 10:51:06 +0530 apsd[76]: peer(68) received XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INVALID
```

Comment: What is the setting in Notification center? If it's only banners and you haven't cleared the last banner from the top menu, you might not get another notification listed there.

Comment: @Alexander No that don't seems to be issue. I have update question with more details.

Comment: @MarcO'Morain 
Try toggling setting in notification center.

Comment: on you app did you set.registerForRemoteNotifications for iOS 8 ? also.. are you sure the iOS device Token is properly being sent? remember APNS are not 100% reliable.

Comment: FYI: problem got resolved after restarting the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you requested permission from the user to present notifications?

Try adding the following code to your AppDelegate's `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

Swift:

```
 if (UIApplication.instancesRespondToSelector(Selector("registerUserNotificationSettings:"))) {
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert, categories: nil))
 }
```

Objective-C:

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert categories:nil]];
}
```